# Backbone view inside a jQuery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I have a backbone view and in it I have a button click event. When the event fires, I want to launch another view inside a jQuery ui dialog wher user can enter information which would be saved to the database.

I have no issue launching a .html page inside the jQuery ui dialog, however its launching a view inside a dialog I am having issues with

Answer (score 1):

If you give the ui dialog an id or a unique class, you can attach a view to it by setting the `el` property to that id or class.  This can either be done in your Backbone view definition:

```
var UIView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.my-dialog-class-name',
    ...
});
```

or during instantiation of the view by passing in an Object and setting the el property inside it:

```
var myUIView = myUIView || new UIView({
    el: '.my-dialog-class-name'
});
```

If you need a more in-depth answer, please feel free to post some of your code or create a fiddle and I can help you work through it.

Cheers,
autoboxer